# Having several BSOD with different messages in new computer

Tags: memory, bsod, memory-management

I've been having several BSOD during the last month or so. I though that they were for some kind of wrong driver or something software related, but tried to update everything to the last version with no results.

Additionally, i did multiple hardware tests to the GPU, CPU, RAM memory and HD. Nothing of these results did a positive match, at least, nothing that i could identify.

Three days ago i updated to windows 10, hoping for my crashes to disappear, but unfortunatelly, they are not. I've been using the bluescreenview software, and here i put the last 5 BSOD on those 3 days just to see if someone can point me to the right direction. They are in chronological order.

Here you can download the full minidump folder from my windows path from drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByWBdLrzM3IgSHlrUF9TWlJReEU

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 073015-5781-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 30-Jul-15 5:24:44 PM
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : ffffe001`221bf828
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff801`b7321da7
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16393 (th1_st1.150717-1719)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\073015-5781-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 348,384
Dump File Time    : 30-Jul-15 5:25:21 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 073115-3687-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 31-Jul-15 7:07:04 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00061941
Parameter 2       : fffff800`c420c228
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000009
Parameter 4       : ffffd000`2435b210
Caused By Driver  : nvlddmkm.sys
Caused By Address : nvlddmkm.sys+55c228
File Description  : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 353.62
Product Name      : NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 353.62
Company           : NVIDIA Corporation
File Version      : 10.18.13.5362
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\073115-3687-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 344,728
Dump File Time    : 31-Jul-15 7:07:28 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 073115-4125-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 31-Jul-15 8:07:58 PM
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : ffffc200`96b59050
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : fffff801`50660a70
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000002
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16393 (th1_st1.150717-1719)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\073115-4125-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 344,920
Dump File Time    : 31-Jul-15 8:08:23 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 073115-4156-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 31-Jul-15 10:34:48 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00061941
Parameter 2       : 00000000`1605ff76
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000000d
Parameter 4       : ffffd000`38144b00
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16393 (th1_st1.150717-1719)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\073115-4156-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 344,992
Dump File Time    : 31-Jul-15 10:35:13 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 080115-3968-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 01-Aug-15 4:58:23 PM
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
Parameter 1       : 00000000`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff801`5cc16fd2
Parameter 3       : ffffd000`20e4da20
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : Wdf01000.sys
Caused By Address : Wdf01000.sys+76fd2
File Description  : Motor en tiempo de ejecución del marco de controlador en modo kernel
Product Name      : Sistema operativo Microsoft® Windows®
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 1.15.10240.16384 (th1.150709-1700)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\080115-3968-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 343,432
Dump File Time    : 01-Aug-15 4:58:47 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 080115-3375-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 01-Aug-15 6:19:33 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00061941
Parameter 2       : 00000000`010a0d40
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000001d
Parameter 4       : ffffd000`26dbcb00
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.10240.16393 (th1_st1.150717-1719)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+14d220
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\080115-3375-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 10240
Dump File Size    : 344,640
Dump File Time    : 01-Aug-15 6:19:57 PM
==================================================
```

I did some memtest86 testing, hard disk integration checks, benchmarks, etc, but i no longer know what to do.

Note that the BSOD usually happen when playing some high resources videogames, thus i've also had BSOD when shutting down computer or closing the game, not only randomly during the game.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to included the dumps. We shouldn't have to go to a 3rd party site, and your questions should be "stand alone".

Comment: Of course, i did it just to help you getting it more organized and clean post.

Comment: share the dmp files from C:\WINDOWS\Minidump

Comment: Of course @magicandre1981 but i dont know how to share them without uploading to a third party site. Here's the zip file in google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByWBdLrzM3IgSHlrUF9TWlJReEU I'll update the main post too.

Comment: some crashes are caused by ScpService/USB driver. Wht is this? An emulator for game console games to play at PC? look if this is the latest version of the service. if not, make an update

Comment: Thanks a lot again @magicandre1981 I have experienced 6 crashes. How many crashes are due the scpservice/USB? This service is a PS3 controller mapper, and what it does it tell the computer that the ps3 controller is a xbox controller. I believe but that i experienced those crashes before installing that software and plugin the controller on the usb.

Comment: remove this driver/Software and look for new crashes. Now share the new dmps.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i have deleted it, and not experienced any BSOD yet. How have you known that it was this software? I've been using multiple minidump readers and any of them said anything about scpservice.

Comment: @magicandre1981 sorry for calling you again, i don't want to create a very long thread of commments, but i've had two software crashes (not screens) and i've updated the main post with the details at the bottom. Maybe them suggest you something and give us any clue? Tomorrow i'll start a memtest86+ again during 8h to see if ram is truly good.

Comment: 1st crash is caused by the nVIDIA driver (PhysX) 2nd update your Audio driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), instead of useless tools like BlueScreenView, I can see the process name of the crash `ScpService.exe`:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff8015cc16fd2, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd00020e4da20, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


SYSTEM_SKU:  All

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_DATE:  03/04/2015

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  H97-PRO GAMER

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8015cc16fd2

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd00020e4da20

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

FAULTING_IP: 
Wdf01000!FxRequestTimer::`scalar deleting destructor'+6
fffff801`5cc16fd2 80790400        cmp     byte ptr [rcx+4],0

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: dac

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  ScpService.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8015cbc089e to fffff8015cc16fd2

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
03 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
04 nt!RtlDispatchException
05 nt!KiDispatchException
06 nt!KiExceptionDispatch
07 nt!KiPageFault
08 Wdf01000!FxRequestTimer::`scalar deleting destructor'
09 Wdf01000!FxRequest::`scalar deleting destructor'
0a Wdf01000!FxRequest::Release
0b Wdf01000!FxObject::DeleteObject
0c Wdf01000!imp_WdfObjectDelete
0d WinUSB!WinUSB_FreePipe
0e WinUSB!WinUSB_SetInterface
0f WinUSB!WinUSB_ResetDefaults
10 WinUSB!WinUSB_Cleanup
11 Wdf01000!FxPkgGeneral::Dispatch
12 Wdf01000!FxDevice::DispatchWithLock
13 nt!IopCloseFile
14 nt!ObCloseHandleTableEntry
15 nt!NtClose
16 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
17 0x0

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16384

BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_WinUSB!WinUSB_FreePipe

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x3B_WinUSB!WinUSB_FreePipe

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_winusb!winusb_freepipe
```

So the tool does some IO operations over USB (Game controller) and at cleanup something went wrong.

Update or remove the tool to stop the crashes.

the last 2 dumps, look like a hardware issue. Please updaet the BIOS for your ASUS H97-PRO GAMER, your version 2404 is a bit old. Update to 2407 which includes the 2405 version, which improves stability. Also your G.Skill DIMM 4 GB DDR3-1600 (F3-12800CL7-4GBXM) is not listed in the [proved Memory list](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H97M-PLUS/H97-PLUS_Memory_QVL_report_0306.pdf). Also run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), look that the current RAM timings match to the SPD values and that `Command Rate` is set to `2` and not `1`.

Comment: Hi again magicandre1981, what i though was a solution for the BSOD, (removing the software as you suggested) has resulted not being the solution. In the last two days i have received two new BSOD, whithout the software installed and even the controller unplugged from the computer.

I have uploaded them to google drive, because i cannot find anything with Windbg. Please, find them in https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByWBdLrzM3Igc19pNlNWbENMQ0U

Thanks a lot.

Comment: ok, I added some details from the 2 new dumps.

Comment: A lot of thanks, as i though i do have ram issues, and maybe a little bit outdated mobo. Marked as solution. end of thread.